# pic timer triggers twice

Tags: timer, pic

I'm programming a pic18f24k50 using Timer0 to trigger an interrupt every 5ms. I'm handling USB interrupts too

Here is the code where I init the timer:

```
void TMR0_Initialize(void) {
// Set TMR0 to the options selected in the User Interface
TRISCbits.RC6 = 0;
// TMR0ON enabled; T0SE Increment_hi_lo; PSA not_assigned; T0CS FOSC/4; T08BIT 8-bit; T0PS 1:2; 
T0CON = 0xD8;
//    T08BIT = 0;

// TMR0H 0; 
TMR0H = 0x00;

// TMR0L 156; 
TMR0L = 0x9C;

// Load TMR0 value to the 8-bit reload variable
timer0ReloadVal8bit = 156;

// Clear Interrupt flag before enabling the interrupt
INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0;

// Enabling TMR0 interrupt.
INTCONbits.TMR0IE = 1;

// Start TMR0
TMR0_StartTimer();
}
```

I'm handling the interrupt here:

```
#if defined(__XC8)
void interrupt SYS_InterruptHigh(void)
{



if (INTCONbits.TMR0IE == 1 && INTCONbits.TMR0IF == 1) {

    T0CONbits.TMR0ON = 0; //Stop timer0
    // clear the TMR0 interrupt flag
    INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0;  


//        PORTCbits.RC6 = 1;
    LATCbits.LATC6 = 1;

    LED_VerticalSyncIter();

    LATCbits.LATC6 = 0;
//        PORTCbits.RC6 = 0;



    TMR0H = 0x00;
    // TMR0L 156; 
    TMR0L = 0x9C;      
    T0CONbits.TMR0ON = 1; //Start timer0

    //TMR0_ISR();

 }


#if defined(USB_INTERRUPT)
        USBDeviceTasks();
#endif
}
#endif
```

I'm using the RC6 pin to do a pulse every time the interrupt is triggered and I'm watching the signal with a logic analyzer. I'm gonna post two images, first one i have the usb connected:

[image]

The interrupt triggers twice every 5ms. Must be something related to USB interruptions, cause if I unplug the usb cable, I don't get these pairs of pulses. But don't know what is happening cause I'm checking the Timer0 interrupt flag and reseting it. So it shouldn't make the pulse if the interruption doesn't come from timer 0

Here is the image of what i get if I unplug the usb cable:
[image]

The interruption triggers, but sometimes the gap between pulses is 5ms, sometimes 10ms, etc...

I would like to get the pulses periodically every X ms. What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: How long is your pulse? I see your LA is sampling at 500kHz, so if your pulse is not long enough to be captured by the 2us sampling period, you may not see them. Can you capture a trace at a faster sampling frequency?

Comment: 500kHz is the max sample rate. I've been testing things and if you give low priority to the timer0 interrupts, I get the pulses like the second picture with the usb connected.

Comment: I would leave the USB out at the moment just to check that the timer is ok and you can see the pulses. Try putting a 500us or 1ms delay between `LATC6 = 1` and `LATC6 = 0` to see if you get a good trace.

Comment: There are probably two separate issues here. Some questions that may be relevant: What does `LED_VerticalSyncIter()` do? What's your clock frequency? Another way to ensure you'll capture debug output is to change it from a pulse to toggle:

`LATCbits.LATC6 = !LATCbits.LATC6;`

That should give you a 200 Hz square wave, so there will be no danger of not seeing it.

Comment: Why are you putting the USB handling function in the ISR? Can't you call USBDeviceTasks(); from your loop in main?